# Pywin32 not installing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32

I'm trying to use pywin32, but it will not install. It claims that it cannot find Python 2.7 in the registry even though I know its there. I recently installed pyHook for 2.7 with no problems. Any ideas as to why pywin32 wont install? All feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try running 'pip install pypiwin32'? Or 'C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install pypiwin32'?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing from wheel file provide here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32